# A basis for $F_{\alpha}=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x=\alpha y \wedge \alpha y=\alpha z\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $\mathbb{R}^3$ be a vector space with canonical product, and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. For each $\alpha$ let $F_{\alpha}=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x=\alpha y \wedge \alpha y=\alpha z\}$ be a subspace.
>
> Find a basis for $F_{\alpha}$, based on $\alpha$.

My work was:

$$
\begin{cases}
x=\alpha y \\
\alpha y=\alpha z
\end{cases} \Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
x=\alpha y \\
\alpha y-\alpha z=0
\end{cases} \Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
x=0 \\
\alpha=0 
\end{cases} \vee \begin{cases}x= \alpha z \\y=z \end{cases} $$

If $\alpha=0$ then $F_{0}=\{(0,y,z): y,z \in \mathbb{R}\}$. So $F_{0}=\langle (0,1,0),(0,0,1)\rangle$.

If $\alpha \neq0$ then $F_{\alpha}=\{(\alpha z,z,z): \alpha, z \in \mathbb{R}\}$. So $F_{\alpha}=\langle (\alpha,1,1)\rangle$.

But now which will be the basis of $F_{\alpha}$ based on $\alpha$ ? Thanks.

Comment: You have two cases, $\alpha = 0$ and $\alpha \neq 0$. If $\alpha = 0$, then you've computed your basis. If $\alpha \neq 0$, then you've again computed your basis, though you'll observe that the single basis vector depends explicitly on $\alpha$.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić I don't understand what you meaning.

Comment: So, you showed that $F_0 = \langle (0,1,0),(0,0,1) \rangle$, and that $F_\alpha = \langle (\alpha,1,1) \rangle$ for any fixed $\alpha \neq 0$. Is $\{(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ linearly independent? For any fixed $\alpha$, is $\{(\alpha,1,1)\}$ linearly independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I. Assume that $a\ne 0$.

Thus every element of $F_a$ is a multiple of $(a,1,1)$. Conversely, if $\boldsymbol{r}=t(a,1,1)$, then $\boldsymbol{r}\in F_a$, because both condition which define $F_a$ are satisfied, i.e., $x=ay$, since $x=ta$ as $y=t$, and $ay=az$, as $y=z=t$.

Basis of $F_a$ is thus $B=\{(a,1,1)\}$.

II. Assume that $a=0$.

If $\boldsymbol{r}=(x,y,z)\in F_a$, then $x=ay=0$, hence $\boldsymbol{r}=(0,y,z)$, and $ay=az$,
which means that $0=0$, which does not provide any further information or restrictions on $y$ and $z$. Indeed, all the elements of the form 
$$
(0,y,z)=y(0,1,0)+z(0,0,1)
$$
belong to $F_a$.

Basis of $F_a$ is thus $B=\{(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$.

Comment: Ok. So, what you meaning is that $F_{\alpha}$ have two different basis? A vector of $F_{\alpha}$ can be writen as a linear combination of $\{(\alpha,1,1)\}$ as well of  $\{(0,1,0),(0,0,1\}$? Let $v \in F_{\alpha}$, then one have: $c_{1}(\alpha,1,1)=v=c_{2}(0,1,0)+c_{3}(0,0,1)$. Thanks for the help

Comment: It depends on whether $a$ is equal to 0 or not. If it is 0, then the basis consists of two elements, whereas if $a\ne0$, then the basis is only one element.